# combining two table in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. The first one is `student` and consists of `name,id,ic,sessi,course,company_code`. The second table is `company` and consists of `company_code,company_name,company_town,company_state`. How can it be displayed like below when I search `student` `id`?

```
NAME:   

ID: 

IC: 

COURSE: 

COMPANY_CODE:

COMPANY_NAME:   

COMPANY_TOWN:

COMPANY_STATE:  

SESSI:
```

Comment: Look at MySQL's [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) Syntax.

Comment: Please provide some sample data, and your desired outcome. It would also be helpful if you posted what you have tried so far as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very Basic SQL Code. What you Require is a join.

We need to join these tables with a common variable and the only common variable i can see is company_code. So the syntax goes like dis.

```
Select A.name as Name, A.student_id as ID,
A.IC as IC, A.course as course,
A.company_code as company_code,B.company_name as company_name,
B.company_town as company_town,B.company_state as company_state,
A.sessi as sessi
from student A , company B 
where A.company_code=B.company_code and Student_id=<id goes here>
```

For displaying result like that in PHP use the following in your PHP page

```
<?php
$sql = "<write entire query here mentioned above>";

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'sqluser', 'sqlpass');
 if (!$con) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("test_db");
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo 'Name'.' : '.$row['A.name'];
     echo 'ID'.' : '.$row['A.student_id'];
     echo 'IC'.' : '.$row['A.ic'];
     echo 'course'.' : '.$row['A.course'];
     echo 'Company_Code'.' : '.$row['A.company_code'];
     echo 'Company_name'.' : '.$row['B.company_name'];
     echo 'Company_town'.' : '.$row['B.company_town'];
     echo 'Company_state'.' : '.$row['B.company_state'];
     echo 'Sessi'.' : '.$row['A.Sessi'];

 }

mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```